# setfacl operation not supported ubuntu wsl

Tags: ubuntu, access-control-list, fstab

i want to set acl certain file in /var/www/html/index.htm inside Ubuntu WSL 20.04 (win 10) using :

```
$ sudo setfacl -m u:wira:rwx sshd_config
setfacl: sshd_config: Operation not supported
```

after searching in internet, all solved valid answer is by editing fstab and remount, buts *this mounting solution its not work in my case*, here my fstab :

**Unedited, original FSTAB :**

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults    0 0
```

**Edited FSTAB :**

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults,acl    0 0
```

of course im even restarting windows and remount after editing fstab, its still shows operation not supported, im also doing fresh install wsl ubuntu,update and upgrade voila its still have same issue.

Comment: posix acls are not supported on WSL: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2750